# python plugin to monitoring linux system

Tags: python, linux, monitoring, monitor

Is there any famous python plugin/library to monitor linux system , such as :

- Temperature
- CPU usage
- Memory Usage
- Disk Usage
- Network Usage

is there any?

thank you very much :D

Comment: You can use system programs through a an exec or a pipe (`popen`)

Comment: You can allways use system calls to the OS !

Comment: There is a lib that cover most of your requirements https://code.google.com/p/psutil/

Comment: thank you Sir Script, psutil maybe cover all my question, gratitude Sir :D

Answer (score 2):

I made this simple application in Python, all you need to install for this to run is a package named "acpi". Change the refresh rate to your preferences.

```
import os
import time
refreshrate = 10
while(1):
    os.system("clear")
    print(os.system("acpi -V"))
    time.sleep(refreshrate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to this [project](http://pymeter.sourceforge.net/) that looks closely to what you want to do.

Alternatively you can use system programs through a an exec or a pipe (popen). More generally have a look to this [package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

For instance, to get temperature, you can simply use `os.system()` :

```
import os
print os.system('acpi -t')
```

Depending on the program you want to execute you may need threading and pipes or not.

Comment: i have looked pymeter, but they doesnt provided temperature, disk, and  memory monitoring, only cpu and network, 

what do u mean through exec or a pipe? i dont get it,

Comment: With such functions you are able to execute thrid party programs that would provide you the information you're looking for.
For instance you can call `acpi -t` from your python program to get the temperature.